# How to force HDFS user/password logging?

Tags: security, hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a Hortonworks 2.1 installation.
I have also installed HDFS browser [(http://bigdata.red-gate.com/)](http://bigdata.red-gate.com/)
I was really surprised, that I'm able to access my HDFS without providing any password!
Just user `pig` and that's it!

Can anyone explain why it's like this and how to prevent these situations? 
I can set a firewall in front of Hadoop but is it the only solution?

Comment: Well, there isn't a specific way to restrict users from using hadoop with username and password rather what you could do is enforce directory level permissions so that specific users don't have access to all the data. Or you could always fall back to setting up Kerberos for authentication and LDAP/AD for authorization for more fine grained access control.

Comment: But the problem is you don't need any password.You just need to know any existing user and a hostname or IP.

Comment: Generally Hadoop clusters are deployed behind enterprise firewalls beyond that for further security you have to kerberize the environment. But at this  moment you cannot restrict user access to HDFS with Linux user account password.